# md-table md-row-select Select all row checkbox not checked when there are some disabled rows in table [AngularJS]

Tags: angularjs, angular-material, angular-datatables

I've table of data with some rows disabled due some conditions.
When I select all rows by selecting/checking checkbox of first column, All enabled rows gets selected. But the checkbox used to select all these rows are not checked.

Due to same reason, when I want to uncheck all chcked/selected rows, I'm not able to uncheck them all.

Can't paste the codepen link here somehow but it's present on this [page](https://github.com/daniel-nagy/md-data-table) 
Example on this page works perfectly fine, even table has some disabled rows.

I'm using "angular-material-data-table": "~0.9" in my bower components

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please show us your markup and code or create a CodePen.

Comment: Got it resolved. Actually I was using 0.9 version of md-table and updated to latest version using bower so found it resolved.

Comment: codepen - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BjvLVJ?editors=1010